# what does tygh ::$app ['view '] in cs-cart exactly means?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I'm new to cs cart and wasn't able to understand the exact meanings of the these:-

```
Tygh::$app['view'] ;
Tygh::$app['view']->assign();
Registry::get('runtime.something').
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a Smarty:
[Smarty assign](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.assign.tpl)